# Complex Integral with constant Function

Tags: complex-analysis

Show
$$\dfrac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{C}\dfrac{f'(z)}{f(z)-f_{0}}dz=N$$

Where $N$ is the number of points "$z$" where $f(z)=f_{0}$(a constant) inside of $C$; $f'(z)$ and $f(z)$ are analytic inside and on $C$; and $f(z) \neq f_{0}$ on the boundary of $C$.

From book's Ablowitz & Fokas.

Comment: You need to count $N$ according to the multiplicity of the zero of $z \mapsto f(z)-f_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Take $\;g(z):=f(z)-f(z_0)\;$ . Then the conditions for the [Argument Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_principle) are fulfilled and thus

$$\frac1{2\pi i}\oint_C\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}dz = N_g- P_g$$